# Make dates in datetimepicker grey?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Im writing a hotel booking system with VS2012 which uses ms sql and in the booking i have two datetimepicker controls. When i select a date in the first one the date automatically gets transfered to the second datetimepicker. I now want when the user opens up the second datetimepicker not being able to select a date that is before the first date from the first datetimepicker. I dont want to use if method displaying a message i just want the dates to be "greyed" out.

Is that possible and how?

*edit (screenshot of how i would like it to be viewed or similar http://i43.tinypic.com/2zpimvs.jpg )

*edit2: its not the control(dateTimePicker2) it self i want to grey out, its the dates inside it that is smaller then the date selected in dateTimePicker1. The screenshot provided is in the area of what im looking for.

Comment: I think you can prevent user from changing the date part but to make it grey while showing the time part normally, it's not easy.

Comment: The user has to be able to change date in the second datetimepicker, just not before the date that is selected in the first datetimepicker.

Comment: Is user allowed to select time part?

Comment: No, the user can only change the datepart, nothing with time is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
DateTimePicker2.MinValue = Convert.toDateTime(DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate);
```

EDIT

Standard controls don't support the grey-out of a datetimepicker. If you want to do this, you need to subclass the datetimepicker or look at a premade control like a DateEdit from devexpress (i think they even have free controls).

Comment: This acctually did work. That removed the dates before the date that was selected in the datetimepicker1. It looks a little strange but I'll use it until how I can solve to make it grey instead.

    dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 1):

Change the second datepicker MinDate to first DatePicker selected date .. like below ..

```
rdpDatePicker2.MinDate = rdpDatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
```